# Css not working on published sites

Tags: asp.net, css, c#-4.0

I have just recently implemented the five star rating system from ajax, into my asp.net site. Everything works fine in locall debug mode.However. Once i publish it, the css does not show up. I have declared all of the css within the content page, not sure if this is why. I am very in-experienced with working with css; so i am sorry if it something simple.

I have checked the spelling of the image url, and have also tried implementing it into the site.css. But as i said, i am in-experienced; so am not sure what to do here.

This is my code as it stands:

The css declared at the top of the content page:

http://codepad.org/m1w39Hep

The reference to the css from my rating control:

http://codepad.org/Kl0BKets

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code.
Give extention as ".css" and not ".c"

I dont think that you can use Codepad for that because it does not give support for CSS.

If you are not using Codepad

Then as you are deploying it in server then check the URLs of the Images that are present in the CSS file for rating/.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your css links is right and your css files loaded successfully